# Making unique function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this YouTube thumbnail/title grabber, inside my message system.

So when a message contains a YouTube link it shows it in a div element.

```
<script>
    function youtubeFetchDataCallback(data) {
        var s = '';
        s += '<br/>';
        s += '<a href="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$player"].url + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].url + '" width="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].width + '" height="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].height + '" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;"></a>';

        s += '<strong>' + data.entry["title"].$t + '</strong><br/>';

        s += '<br/>' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$description"].$t.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') + '<br/>';
        s += '<div class="clearfloat"></div>';
        $('.youtubeDataFetcherOutput').html(s);
    }
</script>
<?php
    $isY = preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $content, $matches);

    if($isY){
        foreach($matches as $m){
        ?>
        <script>
            $.getScript( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<?php echo $m; ?>?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=youtubeFetchDataCallback' );

        </script>
        <?php
    }
} ?>
```

I have this, which works fine until there's two messages in one page, with YouTube links. Then they sends the same `$.getScript()`, and therefore both returns with same video thumbnail and title. How can I make them unique?

Each message has a id stored in `$row['id']`, so maybe it will be something like sending the unique id, with the callback, and then handle them both different ways. Just a thought, as I'm not sure..

(I used foreach, as $matches returns out as a array)

How can this be done?

Comment: Use array_unique http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your javascript parser return a JSON object which PHP can easily transform to an array with [`json_decode`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

the form of the array is up to you, but 2 main ways are possible.

1) if the id is the same when the url is the same, just use id as the an array key when you store the link.  That way repeated links just overwrite themselves.

2) If you don't like that, and you *know* that the urls will be identical, use [`array_unique($links)`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to process the array you get from `json_decode()`

```
$links=array('stackoverflow.com','stackoverflow.com','google.com');
foreach(array_unique($links) as $link) {
  //output link
}
```

Comment: Im not understanding it fully. How can i return a json object? And javascript? I believe the PHP is running first, and then if there is youtube in the msg, then it runs the javascript.

Comment: @Johnson: From your code it was hard to tell how the data was getting to PHP. Assumably, you're passing in $content from a form.  If this is the case,  add a bit of JQuery/javascript to your form so that a JSON object full of links is passed in at the same time.  Because JQuery/javascript is DOM aware, it's much better at parsing HTML and dealing with poorly formed tags than regexes are. Then, instead of using $.getScript to output your `<divs>` just use regular PHP. It's good at outputting HTML.